# How to mail result set from a SQL query thrugh a shell script

Tags: html, oracle, shell, email, sqlplus

I am fairly new to shell scripting and struggling to get results from a sql query in form of HTML table.

I am using following code in a shell script to fetch data:

```
echo "Subject: Test HTML e-mail" > html.txt
echo "Content-Type: text/html" >> html.txt

sqlplus -s -m "HTML ON TABLE 'BORDER="2"'" User/Pass >> html.txt
SELECT * from EMP;
EXIT;
EOF
```

and then I am sending html.txt using sendmail
I want to know how I can add more formatting options to this code. Right now its just sending the contents of EMP table in a predefined formatting.
Do I need a CSS template for this? If yes, could anyone show it with a small example?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked here [Generating HTML Reports from SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_seven.htm#SQPUG017)?

Comment: Yes I did. From there itself I found this. But I am not able to understand how i can customize the output. Too much of ADHD maybe.

Comment: then may be this will help [SQL*PLUS GENERATES HTML](http://gennick.com/database/sqlplus-generates-html) - seems more detailed to me ...